# excel function to combine cells into single line of text?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm new to stack overflow so I apologize if this is a horrendously stupid question. I am wondering if there is a function or way to code a function in excel that will combine a column of cells with plain text and convert them into one cell with the text on a single line? Specifically I want to convert a column of random numbers into a single line of text and insert SPACE+AND+SPACE between them.

Ex.

15133484

12345188

12345888

to

15133484 AND 12345188 AND 12345888

Currently I am copying and pasting all this information into google and then into Word and using find/replace and it is taking forever everytime. If it is possible to just get Excel to do this for me that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have Office 365 Excel use TEXTJOIN():

```
=TEXTJOIN(" AND ",TRUE,A:A)
```

---

otherwise one would have to use:

```
=A1 & " AND " & A2 & " AND " & A3
```

---

Or one can use a helper column, B1 put:

```
=A1
```

put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2<>"",B1 & " AND " & A2,B1)
```

And grab the last cell in column B.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but still:

Reference [here](https://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/)

Step 1:

```
=concatenate(transpose(rngBeg:rngEnd & " AND "))
```

Step 2:
highlight the transpose statement and then press F9, which substitutes the actual values for the formula.

Step 3:
Remove the curly braces, `{  }`, from the formula.  The cell will display the range of reference cells combined with whatever separator chosen after the ampersand sign.

Not a "live" formula, but still far easier than manually concatenating a range of values.

Answer (score 0):

Press ALT+F11 to open Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, 
Insert-> Module
Paste this:

```
Function Combine(WorkRng As Range, Optional Sign As String = " AND ") As String    
Dim Rng As Range    
Dim OutStr As String

For Each Rng In WorkRng    
    If Rng.Text <> "," Then    
        OutStr = OutStr & Rng.Text & Sign    
    End If    
Next

Combine = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - 5)

End Function
```

In any cell type =Combine(Range)

i.e.

=Combine(A1:A500)

Answer (score 0):

use concat function if you can add an additional column in the excel like this:

`=CONCAT(D3:E5)`

Attached sample image with input, additional column, output and formula[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to merge the data in the 3 cells into a single cell with a space between the 3 data set.

If that is the case then you can do it simply by using the Concatenate function in excel.

[image]

In the above example, you have data in Cells A1, A2 & A3.

Cell C1 has the merged data. As you can see, we have used CONCATENATE Function.

The space has been defined in Double quotes. So if you need a Hyphen (-), you can put that in Double Quotes with space “ - ” and it will display the result with Sanjay - Singh - Question

Hope this helps.